# How do you get the pixel location and image size in a fabric js filter's fragment shader?

Tags: fabricjs

How do you get the pixel location and image size inside the fragment shader for the WebGL version of a FabricJS filter? If you just have to pass it in as a uniform is the information available inside the filter or does it need to be passed to the filter as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, i ll try to navigate in the code and remember, i do not touch that part of code often.

In the base filter class there is a method called `createProgram`.
This method is going to return an object that contains a property called `uniformLocations`.

This property holds an object that is returned from each filter `getUniformLocations` method. This method again returns the object using the `gl.getUniformLocation` from the webgl context.

Now fabric has a convention that in the uniforms `uStepW` and `uStepH` you will have what percentage of the unit is a pixel.

In the webgl context the width and height are 1, a pixel is like uStepH by uStepW, that are tipically float like `0.001231432432` and i think the image is in pixels:

```
width: 1 / uStepW
height: 1 / uStepH
```

fabric also uses `vTexCoord` varying to indicate the position (i think because is pretty standard in webgl tutorials all over the internet). So the pixel position is likely:

```
x: vTextCoord.x / uStepW
y: vTextCoord.y / uStepH
```

You can look at the webgl filter `pixelate` in the fabricJS repo to better understand how to access those variables in your own filter.
In that filter the method `getUniformLocations` is returning uStepW and uStepH, but that is unnecessary since the basic filter is going to do the same for us.

So those informations are always available and a fabricjs fragment shader that uses them looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Fragment source for the Pixelate program
     */
    fragmentSource: 'precision highp float;\n' +
      'uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n' +
      'uniform float uBlocksize;\n' +
      'uniform float uStepW;\n' +
      'uniform float uStepH;\n' +
      'varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n' +
      'void main() {\n' +
        'float blockW = uBlocksize * uStepW;\n' +
        'float blockH = uBlocksize * uStepW;\n' +
        'int posX = int(vTexCoord.x / blockW);\n' +
        'int posY = int(vTexCoord.y / blockH);\n' +
        'float fposX = float(posX);\n' +
        'float fposY = float(posY);\n' +
        'vec2 squareCoords = vec2(fposX * blockW, fposY * blockH);\n' +
        'vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, squareCoords);\n' +
        'gl_FragColor = color;\n' +
      '}',
```

Now, said so, i do not think you need to know those things in a webgl filter, unless you are doing something particular.

This kind of question to me smells of the XY problem, but since i'm not a WEBGL expert at all, i may be wrong. If you are trying to build a filter and you think you need these informations to progress further, you could do better at explaining also what are you trying to build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Right now I'm trying to implement a filter that does black and white ordered dithering. So it looks at each pixel, compares it to a value, then decides if it will be black or white.  I'm new to WebGL and I'm not sure what you mean by the XY problem, but if there's a better approach to this I'm all ears.

Comment: the XY problem is that you want to create a ordered dither filter, but you ask about pixel position and image size. Is just that.